# How to get fragment from inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I have inflated layout `content_main.xml` to `view` variable `vi`

How should I get the `fragment` from this inflated view?

Maybe something like :

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) inflatedView.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


public void getMapFragment()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);

    CoordinatorLayout mainL = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    mainL.removeAllViews();
    mainL.addView(vi);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your inflated layout contains a `<fragment/>` tag, i.e. if your fragment is inflated the XML way with the activity it resides in, then you can "get" the fragment via:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

You ask the `FragmentManager` to find your fragment, which is different from asking a `View` to find it.

If your inflated layout contains a fragment which you added programmatically, i.e. you put a  tag in the XML of your activity and used a `FragmentTransaction` to add the fragment to your view (with a TAG!), then you can "get" the fragment via:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
          getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAP");
```

See this [source](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments#looking-up-a-fragment-instance) for further information about fragments.